# How to use AccessToken received from Snapchat to fetch UserData?

Tags: snapchat, snapkit

Following snapkit Login Documentation (WEB), I implemented server side code and am able to obtain Access Token for the user (Section 2.5 at https://docs.snapchat.com/docs/tutorials/login-kit/web/ ).

How do I use this token to actually get user data? There is no mention of what one must do for ex. make a POST / GET request with the Access Token? This I think is the most critical part of the process, and it seems to be missing from the documentation.

I also tried using SCSDKLoginClient.getAccessToken(), I am able to retrieve token from Snapchat for the user who has logged in. However, I can't find any documentation on how to get user data there either. The only mention is that of a callback fetchUserData() but there's no field for Token there either.

Comment: They probably manage token for you. They don't want you to manage the token

Comment: They do in the case where user is directed to Login screen. Once the user has manually confirmed (through deeplink in-app or through web), Snapkit allows the app to fetch AccessToken. For subsequent data fetches, there must be a way to send that token to get fresh userdata.

Comment: They do it under the hood for you

Comment: Thank you for responding. I'm not very sure how that would work to be honest. I'm storing the token in my database. It must be passed into some method (fetchUserData()) for authentication, how else would Snapchat differentiate between different tokens?

Comment: different tokens? 1 token per user. If you log out snap kit will clean keychain

Comment: Hi @canister_exister, sorry for delay. I am still stuck on this problem. I updated the description, could you take another look?
My previous comment was on how would Snapchat differentiate between tokens of different users. Regardless, how does one get userdata from access token? Rather, how do I use access token for Snapchat Login kit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question as I found the answer after long research, thanks to Snapchat Support.

Once you get the Access token by following documentation, follow below steps to get user info.

(Swap out ACCESS_TOKEN for your own access token.)

Make a POST request to

```
URL: "https://kit.snapchat.com/v1/me"
Headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
jSON_body= {"query":"{me{displayName bitmoji{avatar} externalId}}"}
```

This should return jSON result like the following with the user information:

```
{
    "data": {
        "me": {
            "displayName": "DISPLAY_NAME",
            "bitmoji": {
                "avatar": "URL_BITMOJI_IMAGE"
            },
            "externalId": "EXTERNAL_ID"
        }
    },
    "errors": []
}
```

Comment: Hello I am stack here too. may I know what do you mean by "(Swap out ACCESS_TOKEN for your own access token.)" what route should I call in order to make this?

Comment: You should have an access token from Snapchat. Just replace the 'ACCESS_TOKEN' above with the token you got.

Comment: Hey, I would love to know where did you find out where the API endpoint is?