# How do i get the users profile id from the snapchat access token?

Tags: snapchat

To get the access token i followed instructions like this: https://marketingapi.snapchat.com/docs/profile.html#user-auth-via-redirect

and made this authorization link:
https://accounts.snapchat.com/login/oauth2/authorize?client_id=df4c8722-9954-4214-ab24-360167398a1c&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fblizzity.de%2Fcallback%2Fsnapchat%2F&response_type=code&scope=snapchat-profile-api

but how do i get the users profile id and actualy do stuff with the profile now that i have the access token?

i also tried using this: [How to use AccessToken received from Snapchat to fetch UserData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57664956/how-to-use-accesstoken-received-from-snapchat-to-fetch-userdata)

but i always just get the response "unauthorized"

Comment: Is https://blizzity.de/callback/snapchat yours? Then you would do the code-token exchange using your secret, and only then you would have the actual token.

Comment: oh right i forgot to mention it but i did already exchange the code for the token